# Looping of dates Javascript

Tags: javascript

I do looping inside the date. The below snippet is the sample of code what I've done so far. It works fine except when the loop start.

```
var from = new Date(2015, 0, 1);
var to = new Date(2015, 0, 10);
while(from < to) {
   from = new Date(from.setDate(from.getDate()+1));
console.log(from.getDate());
}

//output: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

As you can see the loop start at number `2`. I want it to start at `1` because the date I declared is `var from = new Date(2015, 0, 1);`. I want the output will be `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`. What happen to my code? why it starts at `2`?

fiddle link is: http://jsfiddle.net/grky1Lwz/

Comment: You just need a `console.log()` before you increment the date because you're not logging the original date value.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your first line with this `var from = new Date(2015, 0, 0);` You are incrementing  the date before logging it, which means that the first value you log is 2 when starting with 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the value before incrementing it

```
var from = new Date(2015, 0, 1);
var to = new Date(2015, 0, 10);
while (from <= to) {
    console.log(from.getDate());

    //this should be last in the loop
    //from = new Date(from.setDate(from.getDate() + 1));
    from.setDate(from.getDate() + 1)
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x63fag4o/)